# Using SQL transactions with C# in ASP website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to code a method where a user can pass multiple sql statements in string array format. and create a transaction. Rollback if nessesary. At the moment I get an error saying that the transaction needs a command to execute. Any advice would be appreciated, Maybe another(or right) way of doing what I need done. The following is the existing code.

```
public bool Scalar(params string[] sqlTexts)
{
    SqlTransaction tran = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString)) // Auto dispose of connection
        {
            connection.Open(); // Open the connection
            using (tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdCommand = connection.CreateCommand()) // Auto dispose of command
                {
                    foreach (string currentSQL in sqlTexts)
                    {
                        cmdCommand.CommandText = currentSQL;
                        cmdCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                }

                tran.Commit();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (tran != null)
            tran.Rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug does currentSQL hold a valid SQL statement with each iteration of the for loop?  Might be a good idea to set the CommandType depending on the command to be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the transaction to the command before executing it:

```
cmdCommand.Transaction = tran;
```

---

Furthermore, you might want to be careful. You're `using` the transaction `tran` in the `try` block, but referencing it afterwards in the `catch` block. I would suggest moving the try/catch to inside the `using(tran=...)` block.

Comment: Hi, Yes but its declared outside the try catch block :) Thanks so much for the advice though. It worked.

Comment: Yes but it will be disposed before you hit the `catch` block, so I believe `tran.Rollback()` will throw an exception and not work

Comment: Any ideal why it would end up executing all the sql statements twice?

Comment: @ReidGarwin Not from the code presented. Trace through the program and see exactly what's getting called when

Comment: Turns out that the ExecuteScalar was the cause. ExecuteNonQuery worked perfectly.